# Aspect ratio on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

In one of my website pages, I would like to add a picture with a dynamic size.
To do this, I follow the excellent tutorial of W3school : [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp)

This method works perfectly on Safari and Chrome; but gives me an error on firefox..

Doing the analysis of the containers sizes, I thought the calculation seems to be different..

First, here is the Chrome and Safari method:

- Red block has a width of 50% (respect to the blue one)
- Red block has a height of 40% (because we also use the width of the blue one as basis for % calculation)

[image: Example]

Then, in firefox it gives me this result :

- Red block has a width of 50% (respect to the blue one)
- Red block has a height of 40% of the height of the blue one, and not 40% of his parent width !

[image: Example]

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

.home_box {
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 90%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19 */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#home_picture {
  width: 32%;
  height: 0px;
  padding-top: 18.1%;
  background-color: red;
  /*background: url('../Img/picture.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;*/
}

.home_box p {
  width: 68%;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_box">
  <div id="home_picture"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Could you help fixed this issue please ?

Comment: Several things are left unclear in your question. Please update the question itself to answer those open questions: 1. In your code example, neither element has a blue or red background color. 2. None of your screenshots show any text reading "Lorem Ipsum". 3. You say Firefox gives you an error. What does the error message read? 4. Can you please give us the minimal code to reproduce what your screenshots show instead of example code that is unfit to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Hi @connexo.. There are not blue and red elements as it's only a schema of what I expected. The red zone symbolise the picture (which is in my code..). The paragraph doesn't have any links with the other part of the code, that's why I didn't mention it. I tried to be synthetic. The error on Firefox is that the ratio is not the same as on the other navigators ; it's not an error message.

Comment: My code is now updated so you could have a blue body background and red block instead of an image.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's a problem with your Firefox version. When I run this code (slightly tweaked from yours and shown below) on Firefox 72 I get an output shown in the image below, same as what I get in old Microsoft Edge, Chromium-based Edge and Safari. Is the output correct?

```css
body{
  background-color: blue;
}
.home_box
{
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    width: 90%;
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19 */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#home_picture
{
    width: 32%;
    height: 0px;
    padding-top: 18.1%;
    background-color: red;
    background-size: contain;
}

.home_box p
{
    width: 68%;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_box">
    <div id="home_picture"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Probably you're wright because I tried your code on Chrome, it works, and on my firefox version it doesn"t give me the red box...

Comment: Also note that the way you tried to implement the layout seems overly complicated.